# Помогите с ответом QA пожалуйста

Tags: тестирование

Подскажите пожалуйста ответ на данный вопрос:
Вы заметили поведение системы, которое считаете ошибкой. В документации ничего об этом не сказано. Разработчик утверждает, что это фича. Менеджер проекта говорит, что это не важно, и Вы можете поступить по своему усмотрению. Как Вы поступите?

Comment: Всё выключу и пойду домой.

Comment: Все вопросы к менеджеру. Чаты заскриньте чтобы себя прикрыть да и все.

Comment: есть требование. Если продукт не соответствует требованиям - проблема. Если ты считаешь, что это проблема, а остальные - нет, то эскалируй на вышестоящего начальника и опиши почему ты так считаешь. На данный вопрос трудно ответить. Все зависит от денег: если из-за ошибки компания потеряет много денег, то нужно говорить. Если траты на фикс баги огромные, но профита мало - можно и не фиксить

Comment: *Разработчик утверждает, что это фича. Менеджер проекта говорит, что это не важно* Получите от них всё то же, но в письменной форме и с подписью. Доложите своему руководителю, приложив копии запросов и ответов. Теперь это вне Вашей компетенции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раньше я работал тестировщиком, мы тогда работали в Jira. Если я считал что какой-то функционал не правильно работает, то вне зависимости от мнения разработчика я выписывал баг и просил уточнить данный функционал у проджект менеджера. Далее разработчик отписывал комментарий что это не баг, а фича. И если потом оказывалось что это баг, и этот баг ушел к заказчику, то я просто показывал комментарий разработчика и вина не моя. Советую делать так же.